# Components added to TcxTabSheet are not displayed at runtime when TcxPageControl is hosted in a TFrame

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tframe, tpagecontrol, ttabsheet

I am building a re-usable `TFrame` which contains a `TcxPageControl`. The idea is the frame is dropped onto the form and then I can add pages specific to that form.

This works fine, I can successfully add pages through the designer and at runtime those tab pages appear. However, the problem is any components that are dropped onto the `TcxTabSheet` don't.

If I add a page on the Frame itself (i.e. the base Frame, not the one dropped onto the form) and drop components on that, those show. However, if I drop components onto that same page from the form they don't.

I am clearly missing something here but I would have thought the page control would just work as it would on any form (regardless if it's being surfaced from a `TFrame`) but clearly there seems to be *something* it doesn't like.

Is this a bug or am I just not doing it right?

*Note - I am using the "Add to Palette" option to add the Frame as a component as I want to surface the `TPageControl` properties (incase that matters)*

Comment: What happens when using standard `TPageControl`?

Comment: @LURD weirdly the option to add a new page control is disabled (through the designer) hence why I am using a `TcxPageControl`. Another oddity with this scenario is if I add a component to the `TcxTabSheet` at design time, view the DFM file (Alt+12) and then switch back, the component is no longer there but it's still declared in the form. When I save I am prompted to remove it as there is no declaration for it :S There definitely appears to be some jittery behaviour with this on a `TFrame`.

Comment: In our app we are using a `TcxPageControl` in the `main form`. `TcxTabSheets` are created during runtime and get a `TFrame` descendant assigned. Some of those `TFrame` have a `TcxPageControl` with `TcxTabsheet` components created at design time. This schema works flawlessly. I think there must be something else at hand. We are using `Delphi XE5` and `devExpress 13.2.3` if that matters.

Comment: @GuillemVicens I was able to reproduce this with nothing but a `TFrame` with a `TcxPageControl` - I have reported the issue to the DevExpress team and provided a [sample app](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/97c0ba16-43fc-11e4-80b8-00155d624807), you can try running it yourself to see if the behaviour is consistent on your build. FYI I am on `v14.1.4` & `Delphi XE3`.

Comment: @James, I can confirm the same happens on my environment. My guess is this happens because Delphi compiles the "original" `TFrame` into the form and ignores the one you have on the `form`. Not sure if or how it can solved, sorry.

Comment: @GuillemVicens no worries, I suspect it's a bug. However, I am not sure if it's a bug with Delphi itself or a bug with the `TcxPageControl` component - given the fact you can't add pages to a `TPageControl` if it's on a Frame then I suspect it's a bug with the `TcxPageControl` (since they appear to surface this option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this behaviour is actually a VCL limitation and not a limitation on the `TcxPageControl` component itself. The difference here was the `TcxPageControl` allows the ability to add pages from the Frame instance which is *kind of* misleading.

A workaround is to simply inherit from the `TFrame` instance which contains the `TcxPageControl` (or even just a standard `TPageControl`) and add the pages in there. Not ideal as it means I am effectively creating a separate `TFrame` per page but at least it means I can re-use common code which was the goal.

[Clarification from DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/support/center/Question/Details/T154470#answer-6b9f5dcf-a00d-4791-b7b5-9e44dcfb798c).